# Finding the Natural Logarithm of a number using Taylor Series in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, taylor-series

[image: The specific question]

Okay so I have spent the last 2 hours working on this, tweaked the code a hundred times, but I got nothing. No errors and no warnings, but the answer is wrong. Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    /***********Variable Declarations************/

    double count = 1, totalValue = 0, it, x, z=1, powe = 1, y;

    cout << "Iterations=";
    cin >> it;
    cout << "x=";
    cin >> x;
    /***************End User Input***************/

    while (count <= it)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < powe; i++) {
            z *= (x - 1) / (x + 1);
        }
        y = (1 / powe)*z;

        totalValue = totalValue + y;
        powe = powe + 2;
        count++;
    }

    cout << "The Result is:" << 2*totalValue << endl;
}
```

I know it is a problem of logic (math), but I can't seem to find it. Thank you.

Edit: We are not allowed to use any other library.

Comment: This might be better suited for Computer Science SE.

Comment: @n.m. totalValue = totalValue + y;

Comment: I suggest googling "How do I debug small programs." You should check your intermediate results and see if the program does what you think. For starters i think you are not resetting z, but you restart counting multiplication each iteration.

Comment: Sorry just noticed it. Format and indent your code properly.

Comment: @luk32 I actually did debug it. And no it is not working as intended, but I have no idea why.

Comment: How did you debug it? If you have some data, you should post it.

Comment: I think the error is that you are not resetting the value of `z` to `1.0`.

Comment: Also, the line to compute `y` is wrong. It needs to be `y = z/powe;`.

Comment: @RSahu Do you mean "*not* resetting"? IMO it should be reset to 1 on each iteration... or the multiplication loop should not start from 0.

Comment: @RSahu Where is getting reset? Can't seem to find it. Can you please point it out?

Comment: @luk32 Dude you're the best. Reseting z to 1 solved this. If you can write it as an answer so if someone else had this problem in the future he can see it, since I couldn't find a similar one on google.

Comment: The problem is lack of ability to debug small programs =P. Thanks for acknowledgement though.

Comment: @luk32 Yeah probably :P It's my first time though, I hope I'll get better at this.

Comment: ln(0.5) ~= -0.69314718055994530941723212145818.  Ack, close enough.  Did you try to compute something else perhaps?

Comment: I would not close this question, as it is about a bug in the implementation of a computation, rather than math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to set `z` to 1 in each iteration of your `while`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void main()
{
/***********Variable Declarations************/

double count = 1, totalValue = 0, it, x, z=1, powe = 1, y;

cout << "Iterations=";
cin >> it;
cout << "x=";
cin >> x;
/***************End User Input***************/



while (count <= it)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < powe; i++) {
        z *= (x - 1) / (x + 1);
    }
    y = (1 / powe)*z;

    totalValue = totalValue + y;
    powe = powe + 2;
    count++;
    z = 1; //Without this line you will have very high powers
}

cout << "The Result is:" << 2*totalValue << endl;

}
```

EDIT:

You can optimize your approach, by not having to calculate the power from scratch all the time:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void main()
{
/***********Variable Declarations************/

double count = 1, totalValue = 0, it, x, z, powe = 1, y;

cout << "Iterations=";
cin >> it;
cout << "x=";
cin >> x;
z = (x + 1) / (x - 1); //We start from power -1, to make sure we get the right power in each iteration;
//Store step to not have to calculate it each time
double step = ((x - 1) * (x - 1)) / ((x + 1) * (x + 1));
/***************End User Input***************/



while (count <= it)
{

    z * = step;
    y = (1 / powe)*z;

    totalValue = totalValue + y;
    powe = powe + 2;
    count++;
    //We no longer need to set z to 1, as the previous value becomes useful
}

cout << "The Result is:" << 2*totalValue << endl;

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your method is inefficient and the implementation is wrong.

It is wrong because your inner loop to calculate the `2N`th power is broken. You need to reset `z` to 1 each time just before the inner loop.

Don't do this though, you don't need the inner loop at all.

In order to calculate the `N`th member of the series, you don't need to calculate the `2N`th power of the same old number from the very beginning. You've just calculated the `2N-2`th power of that number at the previous step. Use it.

Comment: Resetting z to 1 solved this, so thank you for that. But can you please explain why the "method is inefficient"?

Comment: @CyberShadow That would the last paragraph of the answer, please read it.

Answer (score 0):

an improvement could be avoiding to calculate the power of
(x - 1) / (x + 1)
in an inner loop
here a solution using an accumulator
written using my programming language VRCalc++ ...

```
// OK !!!

@func user_log_opt (x) static
{
    ratio = (x - 1) / (x + 1),

    accumul = ratio,

    total = accumul,

    power = 3,
    n = 20,
    @while (power < n) {

        accumul *= ratio,

        accumul *= ratio,

        total += (1 / power) * accumul,

        power += 2
    },
    2.0 * total
},
```

for more info about VRCalc++ search for it with your favourite
search engine ...

following there is the C++ version of the above solution
(also includes the Exp(x) function) ...

// C++

```
namespace VRAxSamples {

long double Exp (long double x)
{
    long double result = 1.0;
    long double power_of_x = 1.0;
    long int fact_of_k = 1;
    int n = 16;
    int k = 0;
    while (k < n) {
        power_of_x *= x;
        fact_of_k *= (k + 1);
        result += (power_of_x / (long double) fact_of_k);
        ++k;
    }
    return result;
}

long double Ln (long double x)
{
    long double ratio = (x - 1) / (x + 1);

    long double accumul = ratio;

    long double total = accumul;

    int power = 3;
    int n = 20;
    while (power < n) {

        accumul *= ratio;

        accumul *= ratio;

        total += (1 / (long double) power) * accumul;

        power += 2;
    }

    return 2.0 * total;
}


} // namespace
```

that's all folks ...

Answer (score 0):

Solution in python

```
def find_log():
    n = float(input("Give number: "))
    it = int(input("Input number of iterations: "))

    z = (n - 1) / (n + 1)
    i = 1
    power = 1
    ans = 0

    while i <= it:
        y = (z ** power) / power
        ans += y
        power += 2
        i += 1

    return 2 * ans
```

Comment: OP uses c++, why do you post a solution in Python?

Comment: because i was searching for the solution in python, i did not find one. So when i understood this i posted it here. I understand the question was asked for solution in c++ but lot of people are using python.